# How do I process the results of a netstat and return the PID?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following cmd that produces one line as an output and I would like to get the PID (the last column) from it.

```
netstat -anon | findstr 0.0.0.0:8088
```

netstat output:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8088           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6348
```

What I want:
6348

I want to use this in a batch file to dump the memory of this java process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('netstat -anon ^| findstr 0.0.0.0:8088') do for %%c in (%%b) do set "pid=%%c"
echo pid=%pid%
```

Comment: It seems I forgot to mark your solution, sorry! there's a typo in there which I've fixed up (additional random ' before netstat). But thanks for the answer!

Comment: Have to disagree with your edit - The quote should be matched before the `)` - without that string in single-quotes, the code posted would report that it couldn't find the file `netstat`

Comment: Hmm, you're right... the ending apostrophe was missing and I thought I removed the starting one, but now I look again, I added the ending one.